Geometric Basket Variance swap
I am trying to find out any research papers or models with payoff for a Geometric Basket Variance swap on 2 equity indices. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

What do you mean exactly by a geometric basket varswap? A varswap on a geometric basket of 2 indices, i.e. a forward contract on the variance of a geometric basket?
